# How to allow only 2 decimal on a numberfield

Tags: javascript, extjs

I would like to limit the number of decimals the user can write in the input.
The field isn't shown in error when I write 850,9560 for exemple, here is my field :

```
{
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    fieldLabel: 'My field label',
    name: 'montant_sm',
    id: 'montant_sm_',
    decimalPrecision: 2,
    maxValue: 999.99,
    decimalSeparator: ','
}
```

[My field without error for 880,9794 value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf6o0.png)

[My field with max number exceeded displays correct error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIg4H.png)

Do you know how 1 can set an error when the decimal is more than 2 with sencha ?
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set decimalPrecision to 2, the value is automatically rounded when you leave the field.

If this is not intended, you have to write a custom validator, where you can check the value and `return true` if it is accepted, or some error message if it isn't.

E.g.

```
validator: function(v) {
    var commaPos = v.indexOf(',')+1,
        strLen = v.length;
    console.log(commaPos);
    console.log(strLen);
    if(commaPos > 0 && commaPos < strLen-2) return "Maximum allowed precision: two digits!";
    return true;
}
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2drt

Comment: Thank you, I will try your solution today and give you a feedback.

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks you ! :) I added a param to set the number of decimals you allow in the field

Answer (score 0):

with php:

```
if ($amount!=round($amount,2)) $error = true;
```

Comment: Hey! Welcome to stackoverflow! This is an old question with an accepted and working answer, please try to answer fresh or unanswered questions and keep up the good work!